# GLSL Fragment Shader texturing a cylinder, just getting gray?

Tags: opengl, glsl, shader

Ok, trying to debug another problem I have, I decided to make sure my texture was rendering properly in my fragment shader. But, it doesn't. All I get is a gray color across my whole cylinder. If I comment out "setShaders()" the texture is applied properly in the fixed function pipeline.

All I'm doing in my fragment shader is assigning the texture value to the fragment color. It should work, right? I swear I've got all the pieces in place. grr

Here's the code before I draw my cylinder:

```
vertexShader = "fish.vert";
fragmentShader = "fish.frag";

glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, checkerTexture);
glEnable(GL_TEXTURE_2D);
glEnable(GL_TEXTURE_GEN_S);
glEnable(GL_TEXTURE_GEN_T);
glTexGeni(GL_S, GL_TEXTURE_GEN_MODE, GL_SPHERE_MAP);
glTexGeni(GL_T, GL_TEXTURE_GEN_MODE, GL_SPHERE_MAP);

setShaders();

GLint loc1;
loc1 = glGetUniformLocation(shaderProgram,"fish_y_offset");
glUniform1i(loc1,0);    

glLightfv(GL_LIGHT0, GL_DIFFUSE, white);
glLightfv(GL_LIGHT0, GL_AMBIENT, white);
glLightfv(GL_LIGHT0, GL_POSITION, light_position);
glLightfv(GL_LIGHT0, GL_SPECULAR, white);
glMaterialfv(GL_FRONT, GL_SHININESS, highShine);

drawCylinder();
```

And here is my fish fragment shader:

```
uniform float spec_factor;
uniform sampler2D fish_y_offset;

varying vec3 lightDir,normal;
varying vec4 mycolor;
void main()
{
    float angle, shiny;
    angle = max(0.0, dot(normal, lightDir));


    shiny = pow(angle, gl_FrontMaterial.shininess);

    gl_FragColor = texture2D(fish_y_offset, gl_TexCoord[0].st);


    //gl_Color;//(gl_LightSource[0].ambient * gl_FrontMaterial.ambient +
                    //gl_LightSource[0].diffuse * gl_FrontMaterial.diffuse * angle +
                    //gl_LightSource[0].specular * gl_FrontMaterial.specular * shiny * spec_factor);

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

put

```
gl_TexCoord[0] = gl_MultiTexCoord0;
```

in the vertex shader to fix.

man i have a lot to learn about glsl....

Comment: yeah. i don't think i understand why, but that did it.

Comment: gl_MultiTexCoordN is a built in vertex shader attribute, i.e the input to the vertex shader with the texture coordinates. gl_TexCoord[] on the other hand is a built in varying variable that is used to carry data over from the vertex shader to the fragment shader, the value in gl_TexCoord[], as you have discovered, needs to be set manually. (From GLSL 1.3 and forward both of theese built-ins are deprecated.)